# Operações irreversíveis existem?

Tags: funções, algoritmo, lógica, matemática

Na matemática (por tanto na programação) existem as operações matemáticas (+,-,*,/). Mas todas as operações matemáticas que eu conheço são perfeitamente reversíveis, por exemplo, ao dividir um número, pudesse multiplicá-lo e assim a operação foi "revertida".

Atenção: Operações como 1+1=2 não são irreversíveis, porque basta a pessoa saber 2 operadores, como o 1 e 2 que acaba sendo perfeitamente possível descobrir o outro valor, resolvendo uma simples equação para descobrir o valor de x. ou seja 1+1=2, se alguém tiver 2 valores seria a mesma coisa de ter x+1=2. E outro fator é que se uma pessoa estiver muito interessada em reverter uma operação como 1+1=2, tendo somente o valor de 2, seria como ter x+y=2, e (se não contar os números negativos), os cenarios são limitados:

x=1 e y=1

x=0 e y=2

x=2 e y=0

Existe alguma função, na programação ou na matemática, que ao inserir um valor, ele retorne outro de forma que seja impossivel de reverte-lo ao numero original ?
Para facilitar, vou dar um exemplo em c++:

Para essa função:

```
int divide(int num, int opera){
num = (num/opera);
return num;
}
```

Existe essa "contra função":

```
int multiplica(int num, int opera){
num = (num * opera);
return num;
}
```

Existe alguma função que retorne um número que seja impossível de se conseguir o numero antigo ?

Comment: Cálculo de `hash` por exemplo?

Comment: Explique melhor isso, porque a maioria das operações são irreversíveis.

Comment: *se uma pessoa estiver muito interessada em reverter uma operação como 1+1=2, tendo somente o valor de 2, seria como ter x+y=2, e (se não contar os números negativos), os cenarios são limitados*. Isso que você disse vale pra qualquer operação com 2+ incógnitas, incluindo funções de hash. Se `x+y=2` tem um número limitado de soluções com inteiros positivos, funções de hash também têm, só que esse número é muito maior. Um bom hash tem tantas possibilidades para os valores que os geraram que levaria tempo demais testar todas elas para "quebrar" o hash.

Comment: Essa pergunta tem uns exemplos matemáticos que não procedem. "Operações como 1+1=2 não são irreversíveis," - Como assim? Te dou o número 3, duvido que você acerte quais os 2 números que eu somei pra obter esse valor. Da mesma forma, os códigos apresentados não se complementam (um não dá a resposta do outro se você só tem o resultado). Se vai postar uma dúvida teórica, eu acho melhor deixar exemplos mais embasados para termos certeza do que se trata exatamente. E se puser restrições bizarras (do tipo "só pode usar 1, 2, 4 e 8 pra somar, e sem repetir"), aí até HASH fica reversível.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem, e são chamadas de funções Hash.

"É um método para transformar dados de tal forma que o resultado seja (quase) exclusivo. Além disso, funções usadas em criptografia garantem que não é possível a partir de um valor de hash retornar à informação original." Wikipedia.

em banco de dados são comumente utilizados para guardar senhas, 
MD4 e MD5 ou o SHA-1 são exemplos de funções hash famosas.

por exemplo, no algoritmo MD5 a palava "felipe" tem o valor `7e04da88cbb8cc933c7b89fbfe121cca`

1. não é possível com esse valor obter a palavra original.
2. é possível que alguma outra palavra acabe gerando esse mesmo valor.
3. alguns sites disponibilizam a opção de descobrir o que esse valor significa em MD5, mas isso não quer dizer que ele conseguiu descriptografar esse valor, pq não há como.
   o que eles fizeram foi escrever a palavra 'felipe' e criar uma tabela guardando esta informação. que "felipe" é igual a `7e04da88cbb8cc933c7b89fbfe121cca` no MD5
4. sempre que vc aplicar a função hash em uma certa palavra, tem de retornar o mesmo valor.

Comment: Interessante, existem várias funções Hash ? (Se sim, qual delas é que é a melhor ?) Como poderia usá-las em meus softwares ? È possível usá las no mundo real, ou seja, criptografar algo usando papel e caneta, ou isso é tão difícil que chega a ser inviável ? elas tem codigo aberto ?

Comment: Sim existem muitas funções Hash, Os algoritmos de hash mais usados são os de 16 bytes (ou 128 bits, tamanho do digest) MD4 e MD5 ou o SHA-1, de 20 bytes (160 bits).

o fato é que você pode criar funções hash simples, sim em papel e caneta.
desde que atendam aos princípios do hash.

uma função exemplo: uma função que receba uma string e responda a soma da quantidade de caracteres. é uma função hash valida, não vai ser boa, mas é valida.

recebe "felipe" resposta 6.
recebe "ana" resposta 3.

recebe "rafael" resposta 6.

perceba que rafael e felipe tem respostas iguais.

Comment: O MD5 e até mesmo o SHA-1 [estão *deprecated*](https://blog.qualys.com/ssllabs/2014/09/09/sha1-deprecation-what-you-need-to-know) há algum tempo, prefira usar algum algoritmo da [família 
 SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2). E @silas333, praticamente todas as linguagens - eu diria que a maioria das que são mais usadas - tem funções de hash disponíveis, seja nativamente ou via bibliotecas. São cálculos bem complicados e inviáveis para fazer com papel e caneta.

Comment: Pela resposta a gente vê que a pergunta tem problemas (e se esta é a resposta correta, a pergunta no mínimo precisa ser editada pra refletir isto). Hash não é uma "Operação matemática". São algoritmos complexos que dependem de estados intermediários e uma série de outros fatores.

Comment: concordo que a pergunta seja ambígua, mas ele faz uma pergunta internamente a pergunta dele: 
Existe alguma função, na programação ou na matemática, que ao inserir um valor, ele retorne outro de forma que seja impossivel de reverte-lo ao numero original ? 
então, eu respondi que existe sim, uma função que faça isso.

Comment: @LuisFelipe nada contra a resposta. O problema é só que sem ela, a pergunta não deixa claro se o assunto é esse mesmo, além de partir de premissas erradas. Se a pergunta for editada para refletir melhor o que foi perguntado, agrega mais valor..